# Django Models Filefiled save according to query ID/pk

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite

I am new to django and sqlite. From the code below i will upload my file to 'documents', since there is an overwrite storage function, if i upload the same file name with another query i will overwrite the old one which i dont wan it to be happend. So what I am thinking is to get the query id or pk as the directory.
Its there anyway to store my upload file via their pk or id?
eg. document/name/test.zip
eg. document/name/test.zip

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define a function

```
def upload(instance, filename):
    return "document/" + instance.user.name +"/" + filename
```

And in the filefield of model

```
upload_to=upload
```

Comment: hi bro, just curios am I able to use the name instead of the user.id ? i dont wan to create same file with different user as well. i edited my code but it doesnt seems working

Comment: yes pass the user.name instead of user.id for creating folder with names

Comment: what i mean is using the "name" in the database instead of using user.name. I dont wan create a new folder again if different user go and edit the file.

Comment: if a user edits his files, it will be the folder which was created earlier, no other folder will be created for editing

Comment: how if other user edits the file dosent belong to himself? this is why i wan to make it using the 'name' in database instead of username.

Comment: you have made the name unique right so pass user.name then it will work as you want, have updated my ans, check it

Comment: do i need to import anything before calling instance.user.name? im getting an error has no attribute 'user'.

Comment: found out the problem... using instance.name instead of instance.user.name... With appreciate your help Exprator

Comment: great. glad could help you